# Java ClassNotFoundException even after checking for correct class in library

Tags: java, mysql, sql, bukkit

I'm trying to get a Bukkit plugin to connect to a MySQL server to store data, but even though I put the connector in the build path, it still gives a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver at a line which is creating a prepared statement.

I am very new to SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

onEnable():

```
@Override
    public void onEnable() {

        try {

            getConnection();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SQL Server connection failed, stopping server");

            Bukkit.getServer().shutdown();

        }

        try {

            String[] names = { "uuid", "cash" };
            String[] types = { "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY", "DECIMAL(18,2)" };

            createTable("CashBalance", names, types);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

createTable():

```
public static void createTable(String tableName, String[] columnNames, String[] columnTypes) {
    if (tableName != null && columnNames.length > 0 && columnNames.length == columnTypes.length) {
        String SQLmakeTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" + columnNames[0] + " " + columnTypes[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
            SQLmakeTable = SQLmakeTable + ", " + columnNames[i] + " " + columnTypes[i];
        }
        SQLmakeTable = SQLmakeTable + ")";
        try {
            Connection con = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement tableSend = con.prepareStatement(SQLmakeTable);
            tableSend.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
[21:04:55 INFO]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
[21:04:55 WARN]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at me.TeknoServal.EcoMain.createTable(EcoMain.java:100)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at me.TeknoServal.EcoMain.onEnable(EcoMain.java:42)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:254)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:332)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:402)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:421)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:347)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:571)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:533)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:411)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:270)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:676)
[21:04:55 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

On enable, the plugin should create a new table in the SQL database, but there are no tables in it at all.

Edits:

Connector version: mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar

Testing project:

```
public class testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] columns = { "id", "name" };
        String[] types = { "INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT", "VARCHAR(50)" };
        Object[] things = { 1, "George" };
        String[] updateColumns = { "id", "name" };
        Object[] updateThings = { 3, "Hallo" };
        String[] columnSelect = { "name" };

        createTable("Blah", columns, types);
        insert("Blah", columns, things);
        update("Blah", "id", "1", updateColumns, updateThings);
        select("Blah", "id", "3", columnSelect);

    }

    public static void createTable(String tableName, String[] columnNames, String[] columnTypes) {

        if (tableName != null && columnNames.length > 0 && columnNames.length == columnTypes.length) {

            String SQLmakeTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" + columnNames[0] + " "
                    + columnTypes[0];

            for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.length; i++) {

                SQLmakeTable = SQLmakeTable + ", " + columnNames[i] + " " + columnTypes[i];

            }

            SQLmakeTable = SQLmakeTable + ");";

            System.out.println(SQLmakeTable);

        }
    }

    public static void insert(String tableName, String[] columnNames, Object[] contents) {

        if (contents.length <= columnNames.length && columnNames.length > 0 && contents.length > 0
                && tableName != null) {

            if (contents[0] != null) {

                String SQLcolumns = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columnNames[0];
                String SQLcontents = " VALUES ('" + contents[0] + "'";

                if (columnNames.length >= 2) {

                    for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.length; i++) {

                        if (contents[i] != null && columnNames[i] != null) {

                            SQLcolumns = SQLcolumns + ", " + columnNames[i];
                            SQLcontents = SQLcontents + ", '" + contents[i] + "'";

                        }

                    }

                }

                String SQLmessage = SQLcolumns + ")" + SQLcontents + ");";

                System.out.println(SQLmessage);

            }

        }

    }

    public static void select(String tableName, String idColumn, String id, String[] columnNames) {

        String SQLtable = "SELECT " + columnNames[0];
        String SQLdata = " FROM " + tableName;
        String SQLlocation = " WHERE " + idColumn + " IN (SELECT DISTINCT " + idColumn + " FROM " + tableName
                + " WHERE " + idColumn + " = " + id + ");";

        for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.length; i++) {

            if (columnNames[i] != null) {

                SQLtable = SQLtable + ", " + columnNames[i];

            }

        }

        String SQLmessage = SQLtable + SQLdata + SQLlocation;

        System.out.println(SQLmessage);

    }

    public static void update(String tableName, String idColumn, String id, String[] columnNames, Object[] contents) {

        if (contents.length <= columnNames.length && columnNames.length > 0 && contents.length > 0
                && tableName != null) {

            if (contents[0] != null) {

                String SQLtable = "UPDATE " + tableName;
                String SQLdata = " SET " + columnNames[0] + " = '" + contents[0] + "'";
                String SQLlocation = " WHERE " + idColumn + " = " + id + ";";

                for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.length; i++) {

                    if (contents[i] != null && columnNames[i] != null) {

                        SQLdata = SQLdata + ", " + columnNames[i] + " = '" + contents[i] + "'";

                    }

                }

                String SQLmessage = SQLtable + SQLdata + SQLlocation;

                System.out.println(SQLmessage);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Testing output:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Blah (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO Blah (id, name) VALUES ('1', 'George');
UPDATE Blah SET id = '3', name = 'Hallo' WHERE id = 1;
SELECT name FROM Blah WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Blah WHERE id = 3);
```

GetConnection():

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {

        try {

            String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestBukkit";
            String username = "javaUser";
            String password = "FunTimesWithJava";
            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            return con;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);

        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: The connector JAR file needs to be in the **runtime** classpath.   If you just put it on the build path, that is not enough.

Comment: How would you add it to the classpath from a command line/batch file?

Comment: Use the `-cp` or `-classpath` parameter.  But **first** read the manual entries for the `java` command and the linked page on setting the classpath.

Comment: Can you pls. add `getConnection()` method ?

Comment: The `-cp` parameter is used like `-cp C:\Users\aidan\Bukkit Servers\TestBukkit\java.external.directories\*`, right? and where does it go in the command?

Comment: `getConnection()` look fine

Comment: My advice is to look again on paths as Stephen suggested. Some example could be found even on http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j9c_packageclasspath.html

Comment: @TraianGEICU Thanks, that helped a lot.  Got fixed by adding the jar to the java lib\ext folder. If you want credit, post and I'll check you off.

Comment: Thx. but was not me, you figure out by yourself. More over was Stephen who suggested `cp`

Comment: @StephenC post and I'll credit you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check version of connector jar file.

**UPDATED**

I think there is problem in creating query with String SQLmakeTable. Because in for loop it is appending ""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .." everytime. So please correct logic for creating query for creating table.

```
String colDetail = "";

for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.length; i++) {

                colDetail = colDetail+ ", " + columnNames[i] + " " + columnTypes[i];

            }

SQLmakeTable = SQLmakeTable + colDetail + ")";
```

Comment: Done, any ideas?

Comment: Not the problem, tested that before outputting strings and running them in the MySQL server console.

Comment: But from the shared code you can think that "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " is appending every time in for loop. Otherwise debug that code and get value of SQLmakeTable  variable. Thanks

Comment: My testing project added to question